# Create list of (tm) corpora from list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, tm

I have a list of dataframes, which all have the same structure: 2 columns, the first made up of character strings. I want to loop through the dataframes in this list to create a list of tm corpora of the same length, based on these first columns. Here's some replication data:

```
library(tm)
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c("text 1","text 2","text 3"),y2=c(1, 2, 3))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c("text 4","text 5","text 6"),y2=c(4, 5, 6))
d3 <- data.frame(y1=c("text 7","text 8","text 9"),y2=c(7, 8, 9))
my.list <- list(d1, d2, d3)
```

I have so far come up with the following code, but this just returns the values from the first column of each dataframe as character strings:

```
my.corplist <- as.list(1:3)

for (i in seq_along(my.list)) {
  my.corplist[i] <- Corpus(VectorSource((my.list[[i]][,1])))
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you wanted `my.corplist[[i]] <- Corpus(VectorSource((my.list[[i]][,1])))`?

Comment: That did it, thanks!